# C++ REST SDK Compilation Error (Centos 6)

Tags: c++, centos6, cpprest-sdk

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Linux. Currently I'm at the end of step 4 and I'm running into some problems when compiling the SDK:

```
[root@vultr build.debug]# make
Scanning dependencies of target cpprest
[  1%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/client/http_client.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/client/http_client_msg.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/client/x509_cert_utilities.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/common/http_helpers.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/common/http_msg.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/listener/http_listener.cpp.o
[  5%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/listener/http_listener_msg.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/listener/http_server_api.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/oauth/oauth1.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/http/oauth/oauth2.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/json/json.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/json/json_parsing.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/json/json_serialization.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/pplx/pplx.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/uri/uri.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/uri/uri_builder.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/uri/uri_parser.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/utilities/asyncrt_utils.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/utilities/base64.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/utilities/web_utilities.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/websockets/client/ws_msg.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/websockets/client/ws_client.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/websockets/client/ws_client_wspp.cpp.o
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/build.make:563: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/websockets/client/ws_client_wspp.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/websockets/client/ws_client_wspp.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cpprest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@vultr build.debug]#
```

Been trying to fix this problem for a few hours now on google. I'm not sure how to tackle this error or what is causing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us the source code

Comment: @DavidHaim It's what's on the github page: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk I haven't edited anything, just trying to compile it